# iframe to show the external app as part of current app

Tags: javascript, django, html, iframe

Our needs：
We plan to integrate two django projects A and B, and we have a menu bar in project A, when select B, the right part of the menu can show the pages of B.

So I take iframe to do that, but I have a problem first time,it works.

```
<iframe id='iframe_id' width='100%' height='900' src="http://exmail.qq.com/">
  <p>test.</p>
</iframe>
```

However when I try to replace the src by my tested tools in the second time, it can not show up as I expected.

```
<iframe id='iframe_id' width='100%' height='900' src="http://azsedemo04.cloudapp.net:3000/">
  <p>test.</p>
</iframe>
```

Does it fail because of host?

Does anybody know how to accomplish this needs? or any new idea helps me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both iframes have the same ids which is vague. Ids should be distinct.

Comment: it means I tried twice, replace the first one by second, first works, second doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any error message in developer console? Like CORS violation?
Most likely your application, that you want to embed in iframe, has no settings in the http header to do that.

Check if your embedded application has this header in HTTP response:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`;
It allows to interact and load this resource from anywhere. Once you succeed, change settings to more strict, to avoid security issues

Cross-domain issues are about the communication between iframes. You can always embed any iframe but, if domains differ, iframes cannot interact with each other e.g. execute JS, modify DOM etc.

Comment: Thanks, no exceptions, but I will dig it more, currently the second page show up as blank window.

Comment: yes, you are right, here is the details exception. Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://demo.soft-easy.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.